# page layout for printing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, html

I have an asp.net (MVC) project that has a simple webpage that look like the following.

[image]

The QR Codes are populated using an api to a website that returns the jpeg.

What I am looking for is a way to create a jpeg containing these QR Codes with the ID beneath laid out in a grid of 5 columns.

The crudest way I can think of is to payout the page in the required grid then print to PDF and save PDF as an image.

Firstly I would like to change the layout of the page to a 5 column grid with the ID under the QR Code but I have no idea how to code this in the view.

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thanks that's fantastic. A lot to read and get my head around but looks very comprehensive. Cheers!